# Random number generation with doSMP

Tags: r, parallel-processing, domc

I'm trying to use doSMP package for parallel programming in R. Here's a snippet of the code I wrote to test whether each MC replicate starts from the same seed, and whether RNG will give the same number
The random numbers come out the same. I want each MC replicate to be random(I generate random numbers in run.MC.replicate). How can I fix this?

```
par.mc.result<- foreach(mc =1:nmc,.packages=c("MASS") ) %dopar% {

    source("./src/simulation_math_util_fn.R")

    source("./src/oosMDS.R")
    source("./src/smacofM.R")
    source("./src/oosIM.R")
    sink(file=paste("debug",mc,collapse=""))
    print(runif(1))
            run.MC.replicate(myParams)

    }
```

I'm guessing this behaviour happens because of the way doSMP generates child R processes.
Please help

Answer (score 3):

You need a RNG suited for parallel computing.  Go to the [High Performance Computing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) and see the **Parallel computing: Random numbers** section.  It lists the [rsprng](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsprng/index.html) and [rlecuyer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlecuyer/index.html) packages.

Comment: Very good advice. The snow package even deals with intializing the different streams correctly which I keep coming back to it. I can never remember whether the do* family does or not.